# SQL Grand Total last ROW

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there a way I could get the grand total of each month. I've looked into Rollup but cant seem to figure it out.

Query I have is

```
SELECT t.city,f.fname,f.lname,
SUM(CASE datepart(month,ddate) WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'January',
SUM(CASE datepart(month,ddate) WHEN 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'February',
SUM(CASE datepart(month,ddate) WHEN 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'March',
SUM(CASE datepart(month,ddate) WHEN 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'April',
SUM(CASE datepart(month,ddate) WHEN 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'May',
SUM(CASE datepart(month,ddate) WHEN 6 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'June',
SUM(CASE datepart(month,ddate) WHEN 7 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'July',
SUM(CASE datepart(month,ddate) WHEN 8 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'August',
SUM(CASE datepart(month,ddate) WHEN 9 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'September',
SUM(CASE datepart(month,ddate) WHEN 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'October',
SUM(CASE datepart(month,ddate) WHEN 11 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'November',
SUM(CASE datepart(month,ddate) WHEN 12 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'December',
SUM(CASE datepart(year,ddate) WHEN 2014 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'TOTAL'
from  world T 
INNER JOIN sales F  ON T.ID=F.ID
where t.city = ROME 
group by t.city,f.fname,f.lname
```

Output example

```
t.city,       f.fname,   f.lname    January  total
ROME           John       Doe         5       5 
Grand Total                           5       5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try this?

```
group by GROUPING SETS((t.city, f.fname, f.lname), ())
```

To get `Grand Total` you'll need to change the `select` as well.

And, as a note:  use single quotes only for string and date constants.  Using them for column identifiers can lead to confusing and problems.  Either drop the quotes altogether or use square braces or double quotes.

EDIT:

Without `group by` extensions or CTEs this is a pain.  There is a trick to doing it with minimal modifications:

```
SELECT (case when which = 'normal' then t.city else 'Grand Total' end),
       (case when which = 'normal' then f.fname end),
       (case when which = 'normal' then f.lname end),
SUM(CASE datepart(month,ddate) WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'January',
SUM(CASE datepart(month,ddate) WHEN 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'February',
SUM(CASE datepart(month,ddate) WHEN 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'March',
SUM(CASE datepart(month,ddate) WHEN 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'April',
SUM(CASE datepart(month,ddate) WHEN 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'May',
SUM(CASE datepart(month,ddate) WHEN 6 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'June',
SUM(CASE datepart(month,ddate) WHEN 7 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'July',
SUM(CASE datepart(month,ddate) WHEN 8 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'August',
SUM(CASE datepart(month,ddate) WHEN 9 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'September',
SUM(CASE datepart(month,ddate) WHEN 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'October',
SUM(CASE datepart(month,ddate) WHEN 11 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'November',
SUM(CASE datepart(month,ddate) WHEN 12 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'December',
SUM(CASE datepart(year,ddate) WHEN 2014 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'TOTAL'
from  world T INNER JOIN
      sales F
      ON T.ID=F.ID cross join
      (select 'normal' as which union all select 'total') as which
where t.city = ROME 
group by (case when which = 'normal' then t.city else 'Grand Total' end),
         (case when which = 'normal' then f.fname end),
         (case when which = 'normal' then f.lname end);
```

(I'm not reformatting the rest of the query, but you should not use single quotes for column identifiers.  Only use single quotes for string and date constants.)

Comment: Even though I'm using SQL server 2008 Group sets doesnt seem to work

Comment: @user3512530 . . . Perhaps your compatibility level is set to less than 100.  I believe `GROUPING SETS` was introduced in SQL Server 2008.

Comment: I appreciate the help Gordon but seems as though Grouping sets doesnt work which is unfortunate , keep getting this  message             **Incorrect syntax near 'SETS'**

Comment: My compatibility level is 80 (SQL Server 2000) cant change it to anything higher only below 70

Comment: Gosh.  You are sticking with a database whose main support ended six years ago (and even the extended support has expired).  Someone should consider upgrading to the more recent versions of the product.

Comment: Your 100% Gordon if I do get an upgrade request accepted, I will run the query again which i'm more then confident it will work.

Comment: Fantastic work Gordon the edited query worked wonderfully, I just needed to add 'end' after f.lname on line 3 and in the group by section. Much appreciated thank u.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Using GROUP BY ROLLUP(grouping columns) this will calculate the sum of the aggregated columns.  By default it will return 'NULL' for all grouped columns but you can put an ISNULL wrapper around to get rid of it, or return a specific value.

```
SELECT ISNULL(t.city, 'Grand Total') AS [City],f.fname AS [Fname],f.lname AS [Lname],
  SUM(CASE datepart(month,ddate) WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [January],
  SUM(CASE datepart(month,ddate) WHEN 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [February],
  SUM(CASE datepart(month,ddate) WHEN 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [March],
  SUM(CASE datepart(month,ddate) WHEN 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [April],
  SUM(CASE datepart(month,ddate) WHEN 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [May],
  SUM(CASE datepart(month,ddate) WHEN 6 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [June],
  SUM(CASE datepart(month,ddate) WHEN 7 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [July],
  SUM(CASE datepart(month,ddate) WHEN 8 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [August],
  SUM(CASE datepart(month,ddate) WHEN 9 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [September],
  SUM(CASE datepart(month,ddate) WHEN 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [October],
  SUM(CASE datepart(month,ddate) WHEN 11 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [November],
  SUM(CASE datepart(month,ddate) WHEN 12 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [December],
  SUM(CASE datepart(year,ddate) WHEN 2014 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [TOTAL]
FROM  world T 
   INNER JOIN sales F  ON T.ID=F.ID
WHERE t.city = ROME 
GROUP BY ROLLUP(t.city,f.fname,f.lname)
```

Comment: Thanks Koppinjo , is there another way of adding the grand total at the end instead of repeating the query and adding Union select?

Comment: Im sure this query works but it doesnt for me keep getting this message                                                       **'ROLLUP' is not a recognized function name.**

Comment: I may have found the problem its due to my compatibility level which  is 80 (SQL Server 2000) as Gordon Linoff pointed out.